# How to omit first column in the terminal output and parallely write the output (along with omitted first column) in a file using unix?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, tee

I am stuck in the below scenario.

I have added these in one script named : small_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

uname
uname -r
uname -a
pwd
```

I need the timestamp in seconds for every line displaying in the terminal and needs to write to a file .. Hence I implemented as below :

```
./small_script.sh | while read R; do echo "$(date +%s) $R"; done | tee output.txt

1526635998 Darwin
1526635998 17.4.0
1526635998 Darwin C02V41QWHV2R 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0 ..
1526635998 /Users/home/duraja
```

Now, my query is I am looking for output in terminal where first column (date in seconds) doesnt show, but the first column (date in seconds) should be there in my text file.

Sample Output expectation ..

The terminal output should show

```
Darwin
17.4.0
Darwin C02V41QWHV2R 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0 ..
/Users/home/duraja
```

The text file output should show

```
1526635998 Darwin
1526635998 17.4.0
1526635998 Darwin C02V41QWHV2R 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0 ..
1526635998 /Users/home/duraja
```

How can I achieve it ? Please suggest.

Comment: If you could tell us your sample Input and sample expected output in your post we could help you more on this one.

Comment: Kindly check my answer once and let us know if that helps? Else please post samples in your post with all the details of your question for its better understanding too.,

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 .. I have updated the output. Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: please check my edited answer and let me know then?

Comment: To be clear - are you looking for the time when the script produced it's first line of output or the time when each line of the output was produced? If you added some "sleep 1"s to your posted example it'd be clearer which it is you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the timestamp using `sed` after the `tee` command:

```
./small_script.sh | while read R; do echo "$(date +%s) $R"; done | tee output.txt | sed 's/^[^ ]\+ //'
```

The `sed` regex matches everyting until a space at the start of the line.

Comment: Hi Oliv, Its not working. Also the timestamp should be preserved at the time of script execution which should be the same one in the text file. Hope i was able to put my context properly.

Comment: @duraja What is not working exactly? The terminal output doesn't show the timestamp, the file does. Is it not what you want?

Comment: Yes @oliv you are right. But the output you provided is still showing timestamp in the terminal output. I have added sample output in the description for your reference.

Comment: @duraja maybe the `sed` version you're using is not accepting the regex, please replace the sed command with `cut -d " " -f2-`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared a complete requirement, sample input, nor sample output in your post, could you please try the following, (based on your provided code and question), in which the first column will be printed to an `output_file` and the rest of the line will be printed on the terminal.

```
./small_script.sh | 
awk -v date=$(date +%s) '{print $0 OFS date > "output_file";print}'
```

Comment: Terminal output omitted the first column (date) but in the output text file,only the last line got the timestamp in the text file.

Comment: @duraja, check my edited answer now and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cut command after the tee command:

```
./small_script.sh | while read R; do echo "$(date +%s) $R"; done | tee output.txt | cut -c12-
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for **some** of the reasons to avoid doing this with a shell loop.

Assuming based on the loop in your question that you want the timestamp when each output line is produced rather than the timestamp for when the first line is produced (which would be trivial), and given this shell script:

```
$ cat ./small_script.sh
uname
sleep 1
uname -r
sleep 1
uname -a
sleep 1
pwd
```

With shell and xargs (there may be some bash-isms/gnu-isms in there):

```
$ ./small_script.sh | xargs -d$'\n' -I {} sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "{}"; printf "%s %s\n" "$(date +"%s")" "{}" >&2' 2>outfile1
CYGWIN_NT-6.1
2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
/home/Ed

$ cat outfile1
1526673758 CYGWIN_NT-6.1
1526673759 2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
1526673760 CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
1526673761 /home/Ed
```

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ ./small_script.sh | awk '{print systime(), $0 > "outfile2"} 1'
CYGWIN_NT-6.1
2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
/home/Ed

$ cat outfile2
1526673256 CYGWIN_NT-6.1
1526673257 2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
1526673258 CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
1526673259 /home/Ed
```

and with any awk:

```
$ ./small_script.sh | awk '{cmd="date +\"%s\""; date=( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "ERR"); close(cmd); print date, $0 > "outfile3"} 1'
CYGWIN_NT-6.1
2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
/home/Ed

$ cat outfile3
1526673404 CYGWIN_NT-6.1
1526673405 2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
1526673406 CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Foo 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
1526673407 /home/Ed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the seconds from the data using `cut`. I changed `R` to lowercase, used the `-r` option of `read` and used `printf`, those are off-topic improvements.

```
./small_script.sh |while read -r r; do
   printf "%s %s\n" $(date +%s) "$r"
done | tee output.txt | cut -d" " -f2-
```

You can already split the output in the loop.
You can write to the terminal using stderr

```
./small_script.sh |while read -r r; do
   >2 printf "%s\n" "$r"
   printf "%s %s\n" $(date +%s) "$r"
done > output.txt
```

The disadvantage is that the output is coming to stderr, so redirecting the terminal output or using `|more` is different than you would expect.
When you redirect the lines with seconds inside the loop, you should remove the output file first (when it exists)

```
test -f output.txt && rm -f output.txt
./small_script.sh |while read -r r; do
   printf "%s\n" "$r"
   printf "%s %s\n" $(date +%s) "$r" >> output.txt
done
```